# Error in string sCod = myreader.GetString("here i want put my column from table");

Tags: c#

hi guys i have an error that i cant resolve .
My code is

```
string sCod = myreader.GetString("Cod_Cliente");
```

but show me this error

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid
>   arguments` and Error  19  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'int'

my full code

```
    void fill_listbox()
    {
        string Query = "Select * from cliente ";

        SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, cn);
        SqlDataReader myreader;
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            myreader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                string sCod = myreader.GetString("Cod_Cliente");
                listBox1.Items.Add(sCod);


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
```

help guys
and  if i want to put 2 columns what i do?

Comment: Well yes - have you read the error message? Do you understand it? You either need to get the ordinal column number of the `Cod_Cliente` column and use `GetString(int)`, or use a different member that *does* support fetching by name. I wouldn't personally use `Select *` when you're only using one column, by the way...

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is pretty clear. The following line is wrong

```
string sCod = myreader.GetString("Cod_Cliente");
```

because you pass a `string` to a method that takes as a parameter an `int`.

You could solve your problem, be making the following change:

```
string sCod = myreader.GetString(indexOfCodCliente);
```

where `indexOfCodCliente` would be an integer number representing the index of columns in the results you try to read.

For instance, if the table `cliente` have three columns and the third column is the `Cod_Cliente`, you have to make the following call:

```
string sCod = myreader.GetString(2);
```

Comment: BUT if i want to put 2 columns what i do?

Comment: what i do? if i want insert 2 columns? :3

Comment: @FabioGonçalves You don't put any columns. Actually, you select everything in your table `SELECT * FROM cliente`. If you change this to this `SELECT columnName1, columnName2 * FROM cliente` and you are interested in the value of the second column, then in the method `GetString` you should pass 1.

Comment: SELECT Cod_Client, Nome_Cliente*From cliente; like this?

Comment: @FabioGonçalves Then it's clear that you want. You have to pass 0 to the `GetString`, if you want to get the `Cod_Client`.

Comment: i want get the Cod_Cliente and Nome_Cliente

Comment: i got it xD its working but u know how can i insert 2 objects in one list box? Like: 1,Luis 2,John